# Not able to send mail from android device

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

Gmail is blocked in my tab ,i changed the host name also,but mail is not sending

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 

  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 
  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 

  public Mail() { 
    _host = "host.smartpoint.in"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "110"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "25"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username  
    _pass = ""; // password  
    _from = "lavanya@gmail.com"; // email sent from 
    _subject = "Sample Test "; // email subject 
    _body = "mail to test local mail .....bla bla bla..."; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 

    Log.d(TAG, "mc -> "+mc);

  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {

     Log.d(TAG, " send()  -> ");
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 
      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      Log.d(TAG, " msg  -> "+msg);
      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
         Transport.send(msg); 
         return true; 
    } else { 
           return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("host.smartpoint.in", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");


    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        this._to = toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        this._from = string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        this._subject = string;
    }

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

Can u tell what should i do to send mail successfully even my wi-fi connection blocked gmail access

Comment: Your code is full of [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), please fix it and update your post.  I don't know what it means for Gmail to be "blocked in your tab", but if Gmail is blocking you for some reason you need to determine what the reason is.  If you could just get around Gmail's block, there wouldn't be much point in Gmail blocking you, would there?  The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might contain some clues as to why Gmail is blocking you, if it really is Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

If Gmail is blocked on your network / wifi, you will find that it is blocked in some way:

- The hostname could be blocked on the proxy, which means you would still be able to retrieve mails through a email client like Thunderbird.
- Pop, IMAP & STMP ports could be blocked in which case you could try a VPN based solution.
- Outgoing connections to gmails hostname on mail related ports could be blocked.